# How does closure return work?

Tags: javascript

I have two examples of simple closures and my question is that when should I return the function with or without the bracket? Thank you!

Example 1:

```
function names (first, last) {
    var intro = "My name is ";
    function full_Name () {
        return intro + first + " " + last;
    }
    return full_Name();   <----
}

full_Name("Macro","phages"); // My name is Macro phages
```

Example 2:

```
function names (first) {
    var intro = "My name is ";
    function full_Name (last) {
        return intro + first + " " + last;
    }
    return full_Name;    <---- why not full_Name();
}

var white_cells = names("Macro");
white_cells("phages");  // My name is Macro phages
```

Answer (score 1):

`return foo();` **calls** the function and returns its return value (which is `intro + first + " " + last;` in your example).

`return foo;` returns the function itself.